# How can I add midlet version number from Manifest to compiled package name automatically in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I'm developing program for Cinterion TC65 wireless module. It has OTAP feature, and I need to specify application version on the server by adding a version number to file name.

I need to have something like this when compile my midlet.

```
MyApplication-${deployment.number}.jad
MyApplication-${deployment.number}.jar
```

Is there a way to do this when I create jar and jad file for each version in Eclipse (version number increments automatically)?

Answer (score 0):

ANT build tool can automate build/deploy tasks & use variables.

Answer (score 0):

Below is part of an old sample [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build file with [Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/):

```
<project name="MyProject" default="build">
    <property name="wtk.home" value="C:\WTK2.5.2_01"/>
    <property name="midlet.version" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="midlet.file" value="MyProject_${midlet.version}"/>
    <taskdef resource="antenna.properties" classpath="./antenna-bin-0.9.13.jar"/>

    <target name="build">
        <wtkjad jadfile="./dist/${midlet.file}.jad" version="${midlet.version}" update="true">
            <!-- MIDlet and attributes -->
        </wtkjad>
        <wtkpackage jarfile="./${midlet.file}.jar" jadfile="./dist/${midlet.file}.jad">
            <!-- fileset with classes and resources -->
        </wtkpackage>
    </target>
</project>
```